# GeckoView send event or start function (Android)

Tags: android, firefox, mozilla, gecko, geckoview

I have built the GeckoView into my app. It works quite well so far. Now I want to send an event to the script in GeckoView when the backbutton ("onBackPressed" ) is pressed.

Is it possible to start a Javascript function of an open page within a GeckoView?

Or can I alternatively send an event to the page in GeckoView?

the function GeckoView.importScript() don't exist any more in it...

Answer (score 0):

There are two options:

1. Load a "javascript:..." URI. I'm not sure if that gives you access to the current document though.
2. Load a WebExtension into GeckoView and then use the Messaging API to communicate from your Java/Kotlin code to the content script of your extension.